# remove a class from a tag and add it to another

Tags: jquery

i have following html i cannot edit the html:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <font class="text colors_text"><span class="percarton" style="font-weight: normal;"><font class="text colors_text">
                <b>Price Per Carton </b></font></span><span class="csqft_price">$101.82</span></font><br>
        <b> <span class="percarton" style="font-weight: normal;">Members Price 1: </span>
            <span class="csqft_price"><font class="pricecolor colors_productprice">$96.82<br>
            </font></span></b>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Whenever there is members price in html then `<span class="csqft_price"></span>` of the price per carton should get removed and it should get apllied to $96.82 also the `<span class="csqft_price"></span>` before the font tag should get removed . Please advise.

Comment: yes the span tag should get only applied to $96.82 not before the font tag

Comment: what he means is don't use font tags they have been deprecated

Comment: i have not used it it is dynamically coming in the html

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeClass(el, name) {

  var classes = el.className || '',
    bits = classes.split(' '),
    str = '',
    len = bits.length,
    i = 0;

  for (; i < len; i++) {
    if (bits[i] != name) str += bits[i] + ' ';
  };

  el.className = str;

};
```

Here a demo http://jsfiddle.net/NQq2z/1/